# iPhone 6,6 plus does not show the correct preview?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have created a UI on iPhone se screen.I have added just one image view & gave it constraints as Leading,Trailing,Top Space & bottom space.But when i preview then it does not show full screen but it shows fine when i run on device.

Please tell what is the issue ?

[image]

Comment: what is the constant values of leading, trailin. top and bottom ?

Comment: All zero.Please view the image i posted.

Comment: It looks like you set the width and height, put a picture about what constraint you set

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I suppose that either __A.)__ your constraints are missing nor __B.)__ the autoresize mask has not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode preview Screen doesn't work properly if there is any conflict or warning.In your image, it looks like you set fixed width and height other than Leading,Trailing,Top Space & bottom space. So clear all constraints and add it once again.And make sure that you added 4 constraints only.